# Convert ttf to swf

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

I am using a online flash app and users can upload their own fonts to create a text of their own , I have tried lot of libraries to convert it to register the font in my application , i am hopeless , `any help would be appreciated`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load ttf font in runtime in as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051413/load-ttf-font-in-runtime-in-as3)

Comment: Yes, asking a new question on the same topic is pointless here, you should instead edit your old question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this library: [FontReader](https://github.com/unstoppable/actionscript3--flash--load-and-register-ttf-font-in-runtime). It seems to be an in-memory font parser that's supplied a `ByteArray` and parsed it according to TTF specification. Usage instructions are not provided, but still it's a start on how to get your fonts embedded. Note that it uses a SWF compiler to get the font into your SWF, so it should be available to receive a TTF file, process it and then receive a `Font` object to be used with your SWF.